# Devo evitar usar o "optional chaining" dentro das dependências de um Hook?

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, react-hooks, eslint

Hoje notei que uso o *optional chaining* (`?.`) dentro das dependências de um hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [route.params?.addedProduct]);
```

Parece funcionar como o esperado, ao menos por enquanto não observei comportamentos inesperados. A questão é que esse operador acaba gerando um código como:

```
(_a = route.params) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.addedProduct;
```

<sup>Veja um exemplo no [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIQgAm0ECA9gPwBcuBRzUArnA1lKAOYDcTQgF88IvNRBZkkLA3RSAvLmJkK1ZAxzI2HZAHIASuz3IhpgXhlgAdCXJRKtazqA)</sup>

E se eu tento fazer uma comparação dentro das dependências do Hook (`route.params == null`), recebo o seguinte *warning* do ESLint:

> React Hook `useEffect` has a complex expression in the dependency array.
> Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked. `eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`

Como do jeito atual não teve nenhum *warning*, não sei se o *warning* acima é simplesmente para validação das dependências ou se isso realmente afeta o React, mas o TypeScript acaba gerando algo diferente ali. Então fiquei com a seguinte dúvida:

- Usar o *optional chaining* desse jeito acarreta em algum problema?

Comment: A quem negativou a pergunta: favor justificar. Onde a pergunta precisa melhorar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o [encadeamento opcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486360/69296) é uma adição relativamente recente no JavaScript (estandardizado com o ECMAScript 2020), o TypeScript (dependendo da opção `target`) pode emitir o código de modo a funcionar em "ambientes" antigos.

É por isso que este código:

```
const foo = {} as any;
console.log(foo?.bar?.baz);
```

Compila para isto:

```
"use strict";
var _a;
const foo = {};
console.log((_a = foo === null || foo === void 0 ? void 0 : foo.bar) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.baz);
```

Mas note que a *expressão* passada para o primeiro argumento de `console.log` continuará avaliando para a mesma coisa, concorda?

Desse modo, em *runtime* (fora o código adicional), não há nenhuma diferença entre usar o encadeamento opcional ou essa geringonça aí. A expressão sempre avaliará para o mesmo resultado.

No entanto, a mensagem do ESLint é clara:

> Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked.

Quando se trata de ambiente estático, pode-se afirmar que trata-se do próprio código-fonte. Nesse caso, é bem diferente você usar uma expressão *pequena* como `foo?.bar?.baz` do que usar o resultado compilado do TypeScript (que, embora também seja uma expressão, é bem maior e, portanto, parece exigir mais da análise estática feita pelo `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`).

Note que, embora a expressão sempre avalie para a mesma coisa, a análise estática (que é sob a qual ESLint e TypeScript trabalham) fica mais difícil no segundo caso. É mais código para analisar.

O plugin `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` foi criado para "cuidar" do *array* de dependências do `useEffect` (e similares). E provavelmente, para "facilitar" o trabalho, ele pede que se utilizem expressões "menos complexas".

Com isso, creio que não haja problema em utilizar o encadeamento opcional no array de dependências se a única preocupação for a diferença entre código-fonte (TypeScript) e o código "compilado". A expressão sempre avaliará para a mesma coisa.

Mesmo se você tivesse utilizando o "código compilado" diretamente no seu código-fonte, o ESLint só ia pedir para que você *extraísse* a expressão para uma variável fora do array para ficar menos "complexo" — como a própria mensagem de aviso diz. Não sei porque, mas ele diz que isso facilitaria a "análise estática". Como é estático, provavelmente não terá nenhuma influência no *runtime* do seu código, então pode usar sem medo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu *desconfiava* que era isso mesmo, mas fiquei com um pé atrás por não encontrar a documentação oficial dessa regra do ESLint. A mensagem realmente dá a entender que é apenas para a análise de dependência por parte do *linter*, e não um "problema de programação". PS: Bem avisado do encadeamento opcional ter sido incluído no ECMAScript, não estava ciente disso.